# How to delete all subdirectories with a specific name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-findutils

I'm working on Linux and there is a folder, which contains lots of sub directories. I need to delete all of sub directories which have a same name. For example,

```
dir
 |---subdir1
 |---subdir2
 |     |-----subdir1
 |---file
```

I want to delete all of `subdir1`. Here is my script:

```
find dir -type d -name "subdir1" | while read directory ; do
    rm -rf $directory
done
```

However, I execute it but it seems that nothing happens.

I've tried also `find dir -type d "subdir1" -delete`, but still, nothing happens.

Comment: Does `find dir -type d -name "subdir1"` list the folders properly?

Comment: @Inian  Yes. It does.

Comment: Change `--delete` to `-delete`.

Comment: @TomFenech  nothing changes...

Comment: Have your verified you have permissions to delete the directories and all their contents?

Comment: @MarcM Yes. I use `rm -rf dir/subdir1` to remove one of them and it works. I don't need to do `sudo`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `find` finds the correct directories at all, these should work:

```
find dir -type d -name "subdir1" -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

or

```
find dir -type d -name "subdir1" -exec echo rm -rf {} +
```

(the `echo` is there for verifying the command hits the files you wanted, remove it to actually run the `rm` and remove the directories.)

Both piping to `xargs` and to `while read` have the downside that unusual file names will cause issues. Also, `find -delete` will only try to remove the directories themselves, not their contents. It will fail on any non-empty directories (but you should at least get errors).

With `xargs`, spaces separate words by default, so even file names with spaces will not work. `read` can deal with spaces, but in your command it's the unquoted expansion of `$tar` that splits the variable on spaces.

If your filenames don't have newlines or trailing spaces, this should work, too:

```
find ... | while read -r x ; do rm -rf "$x" ; done
```

Comment: I can see the messages coming from `echo` but all of `subdir1` are always there. Is it because of some format problems or some permission issues? The `dir` comes from Windows System and there are many unusual filenames such as names containing `&`

Comment: @Yves, and if you remove the echo to actually run the `rm` command, do you get any errors? `find -exec` shouldn't mind unusual filenames, as long as no other part of the system does.

Answer (score 7):

With the `globstar` option (enable with `shopt -s globstar`, requires Bash 4.0 or newer):

```
rm -rf **/subdir1/
```

The drawback of this solution as compared to using `find -exec` or `find | xargs` is that the argument list might become too long, but that would require quite a lot of directories named `subdir1`. On my system, `ARG_MAX` is 2097152.

Answer (score 2):

Using xargs:

```
find dir -type d  -name "subdir1" -print0 |xargs -0 rm -rf
```

---

#### Some information not directly related to the question/problem:

**`find|xargs` or `find -exec`**

https://www.everythingcli.org/find-exec-vs-find-xargs/

Comment: Exactly what I was going to answer. But consider `find -print0`  and  `xargs -0` to account for filenames with spaces.

Comment: It should definitely be `-exec rm -rf` instead of `xargs` (if you want to use `-f` at all) (Needed to vote here, sorry)

Comment: @hek2mgl If you want to make an answer of the `-exec` option, go ahead (I will upvote). `xargs` works and is a pattern that can be reused in lots of circumstances.

Comment: The problem is that `xargs` performs word splitting.

Comment: @hek2mgl  `print0` I agree, about xargs or exec: https://danielmiessler.com/blog/linux-xargs-vs-exec/  ;regarding the `-f` I saw OP had it, so I added too.

Comment: @Kent Looks like the guy who wrote the `xargs vs. exec` blog post is missing the opportunity to use `-exec ls {} +`.

Comment: @Kent although in this case we know the subdir only occurs once, so `xargs`' big win isn't there. However, I think it's worth sticking to one idiom whenever you're "doing something with the stuff `find` finds".

Comment: No, no, no, no, ... ! `xargs` introduces problems but doesn't solve problems here. It can be considered *wrong*

Comment: @slim indeed, I always do `find|xargs` I knew there is `-exec` but never (really) used it.  not because it is bad, it is easy for me to remember. :)

Comment: @hek2mgl if you meant the space in filename problem, I agree, `print0` and `-0` are required. I don't see other problems with xargs... pls tell if I am wrong, after all I didn't use `exec`, perhaps I missed something

Comment: `-exec ... +` is new to me. I think it may have backward-compatibility issues, but that might not matter to some people. `-print0 / -0` solves all the problems I know of with `xargs`.

Comment: @hek2mgl some more info about exec and xargs... you are right `exec +` is fast too. but I would stick to `xargs`, it is fast and can combine with other commands. https://www.everythingcli.org/find-exec-vs-find-xargs/

Comment: When `-print0` is used together with `xargs -0` the command is safe, that's true. (That was not used, in the moment I voted).. Anyhow why should I join by `\0`, pipe to an extra program, split by `\0` again instead of just using `-exec rm -r {} +`. Afar from the performance "issues", even the less keystrokes are a benefit of `-exec`.

Comment: Anyhow, the command is not wrong any more. That's why I've removed my vote.

Comment: @hek2mgl thank you. I put the link in answer. and learned `exec +` today, thanks to your comments.

Comment: @hek2mgl So I just found the GNU findutils changelog, and `-exec ... {} +` was added in 2005. That's a long time ago, but a while after I learned shell scripting :-O.  Piping to xargs with `\0` is slightly *faster* according to my simple benchmark, which makes some sense because it slightly parallelizes things, but I can agree that `-exec ... {}` could be seen as cleaner.

Comment: If there are many (many) files, piping output to a separate program to handle deletions (i.e. piping to `xargs -0 -n 1` or `while read -r -d $'\0'`) has the advantage of using a *separate process*, which could be advantageous in multi-CPU environments. Also, it doesn't depend on a super-long command line. If you were trying to match, say, millions of files, the single command line generated by `xargs` alone or `find ... -exec .. +` would barf.

Comment: @ghoti First, thanks for teaching me the word `barf`. Never heard before but it is good to know :) .. About the topic: `+`, or `xargs` will just pass as many arguments as possible to avoid `too many arguments` errors. Are those errors what you meant with *barf*?

Comment: PS: Imo if there are millions of files, two separate processes may be of importance: `find` and `rm`. Atm I don't see the advantage of the extra `xargs` process. (But I don't know how `find` is implemented under the hood. Also both `find` and `rm` would access the same filesystem. I don't understand the consequences of this (in Linux) completely atm but still don't see the usefulness of (good old) `xargs`). I personally see the advantage of `xargs` more when used with programs which don't support something like `-exec`.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it seems you've tried to use `while` with `find`. The following substitution may help you:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do rm -rf "$dir"; done < <(find dir -type d -name "subdir" -print0)
```